# Forcing anti-aliasing using css: Is this a myth?

Tags: css, fonts

Recently a client has complained about the appearance of a system font in IE6. Basically th issue is that IE6 doesn't support font-smoothing/anti-aliasing (I know you can turn it on in an OS setting or something). But someone threw out this gem:

"You can force font anti-alias in css by using pt instead of px."

I did a quick POC in various browsers and saw no difference. I found one reference to it online, last post on this forum:

http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3280638.htm

This sounds like the equivalent of a web developer urban myth, my feeling is it's BS. Has anyone ever encountered it?

Comment: Probably the closest thing to this is that you can make IE stop using cleartype by using certain css properties, namely opacity.. but naw

Comment: This is an old question, and browser abilities have changed.  Check out the answer below that mentions "font-smoothing: antialiased;"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, there's not really any way to control this as a web developer.

Small exceptions are that you can do some fake forcing of anti-aliasing by using Flash through [sIFR](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr/), and some browsers won't anti-alias bitmap/pixel fonts (as they shouldn't, more info: [Anti-Aliasing](http://daringfireball.net/2003/03/antialiasing) / [Anti-Anti-Aliasing](http://daringfireball.net/2003/03/antiantialiasing)).

Also, as Daniel mentioned, it's ideal to be using `em` units for all fonts, see [The Incredible Em & Elastic Layouts with CSS](http://jontangerine.com/log/2007/09/the-incredible-em-and-elastic-layouts-with-css) for more information about this.

Comment: This is somewhat offtopic, but I'm not a proponent in elastic/bulletproof CSS layouts. They exponentially increase the amount of work if you're trying for a true "zoom" effect on a complex layout, and all A grade browsers except for IE6 support actual page zooming.

Comment: Note - there is another option called "cufon" that is an html5 font replacement that support AA and is easier then sIRF (in my experience) http://cufon.shoqolate.com

Comment: @Sasha, there aren't really words strong enough to express how much I disagree with you (and the six people who upvoted you) on this. Yes, layouts that work at a variety of font sizes are more work, there's no doubt about it. But there are now more screen resolutions out there than ever before, and by only catering to the default font size on your monitor you are abandoning everyone else, including users of mobiles, netbooks and tablets, to their fate.

Comment: At the risk of veering further off-topic, there's a difference between elastic layouts and responsive layouts. Using ems instead of pixels doesn't really help with different screen resolutions.

Comment: @RyanBrodie You're joking, right? You actually down-voted an answer that was perfectly valid THREE YEARS ago? And FWIW, your answer is still wrong because the OP was asking about IE6, which was a valid browser to worry about... THREE YEARS AGO!

Comment: @RyanBrodie Wow... I was feeling punchy when I wrote that and honestly didn't expect a reply, certainly not one as considerate as yours. That was incredibly cool of you Ryan.

Answer (score 51):

## Oh yes you can:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

[Source for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17927764/922522), thanks [Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922522/justin) for the heads up.

Comment: Firefox 25+ now has font smoothing in OSX: `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;`  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17927764/922522

Comment: cannot find any doc about font-smoothing and chrome dev tool doesn't recognize it

Answer (score 39):

There's these exciting new properties in CSS3:

```
font-smooth:always;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Still not done much testing with them myself though, and they almost definitely won't be any good for IE. Could be useful for Chrome on Windows or maybe Firefox though. Last time I checked, they didn't antialias small stuff automatically like they do in OSX.

**UPDATE**

These are not supported in IE or Firefox. The font-smooth property is only available in iOS safari as far as I remember

Answer (score 15):

I found a really awkward solution using the zoom and filter ms-only properties
Example (try with no aa, standard and cleartype):
http://nadycoon.hu/special/archive/internet-explorer-force-antialias.html

How it works:

-zoom up text with zoom:x, x>1

-apply some blur(s) (or any other filter)

-zoom down with zoom:1/x

It's a bit slow, and very! memory-hungry method, and on non-white backgrounds it has some slight dark halo.

CSS:

```
.insane-aa-4b                  { zoom:0.25; }
.insane-aa-4b .insane-aa-inner { zoom:4; }
.insane-aa-4b .insane-aa-blur  { zoom:1;
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelRadius=2);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="insane-aa-4b">
<div class="insane-aa-blur">
<div class="insane-aa-inner">
  <div style="font-size:12px;">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div></div></div>
```

You can use this short jQuery to force anti-aliasing, just add the ieaa class to anything:

```
$(function(){ $('.ieaa').wrap(
'<div style="zoom:0.25;"><div style="zoom:1;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelRadius=2);"><div style="zoom:4;"><'+'/div><'+'/div><'+'/div>'
); });
```

Comment: Has anyone tried/verified this? I tried the example link above in WinXP + Firefox 3.x and I'm not really seeing the desired AA effect.

Comment: It creates a blurry mess in the new IE9, so don't use it :)

Comment: Pretty laggy but impressive solution :)

Comment: The basic idea is: blur the rendering, but with a very tiny blur radius (less than a pixel).  It's no substitute for proper anti-aliasing/ClearType, and will likely just decrease readability.  It will, however, fix some rather nasty font rendering problems when using bolder-than-bold weights.

Answer (score 8):

Adding the following line of CSS works for Chrome, but not Internet Explorer or Firefox.

`text-shadow: #fff 0px 1px 1px;`

Comment: What does this have to do with MS ClearType?

Comment: Excellent! This works for me. P.S. I did change the second pixel value to 0 so as to make the smoothing of the text even on all sides:     `text-shadow: #fff 0 0 1px;`

Comment: I know this is wildly out of date and probably shouldn't be used, but you can now use the dynamic color already being used on a font globally with `text-shadow: 0 0 1px currentColor;`

Answer (score 7):

I disagree with Chad Birch. We **can** force anti-aliasing, at least in **Chrome** using a simple css trick with the `-webkit-text-stroke` property:-

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px transparent;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

I say its a myth.

The only difference I've found between pt, px, and percent based fonts is in terms of what IE will scale when the Menu > View > Text Size > ?Setting? is changed.

IIRC:

- the `px` and `pt` based fonts will NOT scale
- `percent` based fonts scale in IE just fine

AFAIK:

- The font anti-aliasing is mostly controlled by the windows setting for `"ClearType"` or in the case of IE7/IE8 the IE-specific setting for `ClearType`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you got it a bit wrong.  Someone in the thread you pasted says that you can **stop** anti-aliasing by using `px` instead of `pt`, not that you can **force** it by using the latter.  I'm a bit sceptical to both of the claims though...

Answer (score 2):

The px to pt fix worked for me on a site that uses a font from Google Web Fonts.  On Win7 - IE8 it correctly fixed the lack of anti-alias rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Using an opacity setting of 99% (through the DXTransform filters) actually forces Internet Explorer to turn off ClearType, at least in Version 7. [Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/08/31/730887.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice way to achieve anti-aliasing:

```
text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is anyway to force a browser to do anything. It would depend on the system configuration, the font used, browser settings, etc. It sounds like BS to me too.

As a note, always use relative sizes not PX.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the most exhaustive solution can be found at http://www.elfboy.com/blog/text-shadow_anti-aliasing/.  Works in Firefox and Chrome, although Firefox is not quite as effective as Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, Gecko and WebKit support the the

```
text-rendering
```

property as well.

Comment: Yes, but bear in mind that in some versions of Chhome, text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; causes all kinds of text-rendering problems (e.g. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=78529). Oh, the irony.

Answer (score 0):

Not a pure CSS but natively supported method without any font replacement hacks:
Simply convert your font to SVG and place it higher(before WOFF or TTF) in @font-face order. Voila! Fonts are smooth now, because they're no longer treated as a font but an SVG shape which will be nicely smoothened.

Note: I noticed that SVG can weight more than WOFF or TTF.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix...

```
.text {
            font-size: 15px;  /* for firefox */
            *font-size: 90%; /* % restart the antialiasing for ie, note the * hack */
            font-weight: bold; /* needed, don't know why! */
        }
```