# IE8 - Font anti-alias strange behaviour (w/ prints. example)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, font-face, antialiasing

As every web-developer I'm tired of Internet Explorer...
I'm working on a new website and use font-face (the problem may not be related but just in case...):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ArabicTypesettingRegular';
    src: url('arabtype-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('../../../partilhado/fontes/arabtype-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../../../partilhado/fontes/arabtype-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../../../partilhado/fontes/arabtype-webfont.svg#webfontz5xQb9Ii') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The problem that I'm facing with is related w/ anti-alias/font smoothing... It's working fine in every browser but IE8 (I don't care about older versions)... To complicate it a little bit more, it works on some titles, but in some others it fails.. I can assure that the elements share the same classes, as you can see in my example [HIGHER RESOLUTION IMAGE HERE](http://www.dev.multisnet.com/anti-alias-ie-problem/ie-vs-firefox-anti-alias.png)..

[image]

Css class:

```
.title{
font-family:"Arabic Typesetting";
font-size:24px;
margin-top:10px;
}
```

I tried to change it from 'px' to 'pt' but it didn't solve my problem...

[EDIT] I remove font-face and with Arial the problem remains the same...[/EDIT]

Do you have any ideas? Or some comments about this issue...

---

Thanks in advance,

Pedro

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761778/forcing-anti-aliasing-using-css-is-this-a-myth

Comment: I read that before post my question... It doesn't help me because it said that "IE6 doesn't support font-smoothing/anti-aliasing". I know that, my problem is related only with IE8. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are using a css filter alpha opacity on the background of the first title.
It cancels the anti-aliasing.
You will find a fix (add and remove a background color) [here](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/09/02/how-to-make-cleartype-font-face-fonts-and-css-visual-filters-play-nicely-together/).

Comment: I was using a PNG24 1x1 image for that background. I solved my problem.. It was in fact related with that image. I changed it for a solid background colour and the font is no longer sharpen. However, the strange for me is the other text (on the right side) is also over a PNG24 with transparency (it might not be noticeable in that image) and IE smooth it.. Strange, isn't it?
Thanks for your help!