# Does CSS support text anti-aliasing such as "crisp, sharp etc" yet?

Tags: text, css, antialiasing

I have some text in Photoshop & it's set to "crisp". When I put it on my site it doesn't quite look the same.

Does anything exist in CSS yet that I can use to make it crisp? Or not?

Or do you have any suggestions to achieve a similar effect?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not only is it not possible, but different browsers on the market enforce different antialiasing settings, meaning that you can't get consistent results, even if they are not what you want.

For a good article on how the various browsers deal with font rendering, I'd suggest reading this: http://blog.typekit.com/2010/10/21/type-rendering-web-browsers/

Answer (score 7):

this is what I found on a big company's web site:

```
body, table, form {
font: 12px/18px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; 
background-color: transparent; 
color: #333; 
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}
```

Comment: -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; Windows has no support for it

Comment: Lucida Grande, hmm, I wonder which big company that could be? 

Answer (score 6):

What you're really asking is:

"Is it possible to control anti-aliasing from the web development perspective?"

The answer, for now, and for at least some time into the future (until OS/browser vendors start giving that kind of developmental control [don't hold your breath]) is undeniably: NO.

- [Forcing AA is a myth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761778/forcing-anti-aliasing-using-css-is-this-a-myth)
- [No way to smooth text](http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3271636.htm)
- [Use images to simulate AA](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=54688)

Comment: In addition to not being able to force much on (informed) end users, the CSS for controlling text rendering was not incredibly well supported last I checked (admittedly some time ago).  Presumably it will be well supported some day if it isn't already, and then you'll have what you want at least for people interested in viewing things as you want them to.

Answer (score 2):

[Forcing anti-aliasing using css: Is this a myth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761778/forcing-anti-aliasing-using-css-is-this-a-myth)

Answer (score 0):

Try This code snippet

```
 body {
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Comment: This does not work in any modern browser, hence the down vote.