# Can I set Anti Aliasing in CSS?

Tags: css, fonts, web, coda

I'm using Google Web Fonts so I can use the font Coda on my web page. However the font looks poor.

I installed the font on my computer and opened photoshop and set the anti aliasing to sharp and it looks fine. Any idea if I can set the AA in CSS?

Cheers

Comment: Needs more info. What browsers does it look poor in? Can you show an example?

Comment: There's `text-rendering` but it doesn't really do much for AA... there are a number of `text-shadow` hacks and that kind of stuff too, but those are hacks more than anything else.

Comment: `-webkit-font-smoothing` also exists, but only applies to WebKit-based browsers on OS X and Safari on Windows.

Comment: This thread may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761778/forcing-anti-aliasing-using-css-is-this-a-myth

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a feature of CSS. Each browser does it differently anyway.