# Webfont Smoothing and Antialiasing in Firefox and Opera

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, antialiasing

I have custom-made web fonts used on my site. To style my rendering output, I used the following code:

```css
//-webkit-text-stroke-width: .05px;
//-webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

This works fine on Safari and Chrome (edges are sharper and lines are thinner). 
Is there any way of implementing the same style on Firefox and Opera?

Comment: It would be a good idea to stop doing that and read why here: http://www.usabilitypost.com/2012/11/05/stop-fixing-font-smoothing/

Comment: ^ this is a broad generalization and it's fine to use font-smoothing. It's the rendering issue that is the problem, not the designer behavior. When you design a layout and the font appears to be semi-bold due to the rendering engine then it's the engine that needs fixed, not the layout.

Comment: It's not entirely a broad generalization. The article says that subpixel rendering was primarily intended for making light text on dark backgrounds more readable (i.e. accessible), and making a broad CSS definition like `body { -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }` is too heavy-handed.

Comment: My web fonts that are dark on light backgrounds are getting "faux bolded" as well.  I say "antialiased" all around.

Comment: Maximilian's answer worked for me!

Comment: the usability post above is in support of the op. Chrome and Safari on Mac use subpixel smooting instead of antialiased as a DEFAULT. For a company that touts it's design sense, Apple sure doesn't get it with antialiasing. I guess that's why they keep squeezing in more pixels per inch. You get enough and this doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: How a page displays is up to the designer, including all typographic attributes. It's their responsibility to ensure usability, consistency, and appeal across the widest range of platforms. Access to font smoothing attributes via CSS enables greater control. Like anything, it can be misused in the wrong hands. But touting personal philosophy rather than answering the question isn't helpful.

Comment: Surprisingly, above certain font-size, AA kicks in...

Comment: That is why I set `gfx.downloadable_fonts.enabled` to `false` in FF. Now, text became readable even in size 4-8 px on a 24" display with 1920x1600. Letters became sharpen, legible, thin and pixel-wide. Now, there is no blurred antialiased text, which makes text difficult to read. If special graphical symbols that are embedded into a custom font are not present in a standard system font like Tahoma, Verdana or Arial, then I just ignore such unprintable symbols or websites at all.

Answer (score 195):

As Opera is powered by Blink since Version 15.0 `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` does also work on Opera.

Firefox has finally added a property to enable grayscaled antialiasing. After a long [discussion](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=857142) it will be available in Version 25 with another syntax, which points out that this property only works on OS X.

```
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

This should fix blurry icon fonts or light text on dark backgrounds.

```
.font-smoothing {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

You may read [**my post about font rendering on OSX**](http://max.hn/thoughts/better-font-rendering-on-osx) which includes a Sass mixin to handle both properties.

Comment: Windows and Linux use different rendering algorithms for fonts than OSX.

Answer (score 15):

Well, Firefox does not support something like that.

In the reference page from Mozilla specifies `font-smooth` as CSS property controls the application of anti-aliasing when fonts are rendered, but this property has been **removed** from this specification and is currently not on the standard track.

This property is only supported in Webkit browsers.

If you want an alternative you can check this:

- [Text-Shadow Anti-Aliasing | Philip Renich, Websites - blog](http://www.elfboy.com/blog/text-shadow_anti-aliasing/)
- [cufón - fonts for the people](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/)

Comment: Well, the problem I have is that my fonts look to "bold" and bloated in firefox and opera. With `-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;` I could fix it in Safari and Chrome. I'd love to find any "hack" to make my fonts a little bit lighter in Firefox as well. I thought of applying a white `text-shadow` to it in moz only but there is no way to apply a "inset" text-shadow that would make the font lighter.

Comment: @matt You can try some CSS advices in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761778/forcing-anti-aliasing-using-css-is-this-a-myth Maybe you find some CSS alternative.

Answer (score 11):

**Case: Light text with jaggy web font on dark background Firefox (v35)/Windows**
Example: [Google Web Font Ruda](http://codepen.io/Volker_E/pen/azVLbd)

Surprising solution - 
adding following property to the applied selectors:

```css
selector {
    text-shadow: 0 0 0;
}
```

Actually, result is the same just with `text-shadow: 0 0;`, but I like to explicitly set blur-radius.

It's not an universal solution, but might help in some cases. Moreover I haven't experienced (also not thoroughly tested) negative performance impacts of this solution so far.

Comment: Does nothing in helping

Comment: this will cause bolder fonts on chrome based on the font

Comment: @BenSewards Would you provide a font where you ran into getting bolder font rendering? Or maybe even a CodePen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @VolkerE. thanks for the great solution. I've the same annoying problem with the Source Code Pro Font in a Sticky Header. When I scroll the font get's very small and with your text-shadow the font doesn't make any problems.

Comment: On current chrome (58.0.3029.110) the "smooth" text actually looks _really_ horrible. (the "jaggy" text is somewhat better)

Answer (score 7):

After running into the issue, I found out that my WOFF file was not done properly, I sent a new TTF to [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) which gave me a proper WOFF that was smooth in Firefox without adding any extra CSS to it.

Comment: is it in windows?

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution with this link :
http://pixelsvsbytes.com/blog/2013/02/nice-web-fonts-for-every-browser/

Step by step method :

- send your font to a WebFontGenerator and get the zip
- find the TTF font on the Zip file
- then, on linux, do this command (or install by `apt-get install ttfautohint`):
  `ttfautohint --strong-stem-width=g neosansstd-black.ttf neosansstd-black.changed.ttf`
- then, one more, send the new TTF file (neosansstd-black.changed.ttf) on the WebFontGenerator
- you get a perfect Zip with all your webfonts !

I hope this will help.

Comment: Did a great job in fixing font jagging during css-transitions (though not removed it completely). I used FontSquirrel generator with TTFAutohint option

Comment: I used Fontie to re-generate my WOFF, WOFF2, EOT and SVG files with autohint for Windows enabled.

Answer (score 4):

... in the body tag and these from the content and the typeface looks better in general...

```
body, html {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
font-smooth: always;

font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}


#content {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry... what is "reinschreiben"?  Most of us don't speak German, so it'd be nice if you made your entire post in English.

Comment: Oh please, I apologize had translated with Google and somehow the wrong word since slipped :)

Answer (score 3):

When the color of text is dark, in Safari and Chrome, I have better result with the text-stroke css property.

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px #000;
```

Comment: The question is about Firefox and Opera. so this answer has nothing to do with the question

Answer (score -4):

Adding

```
font-weight: normal;
```

To your @font-face fonts will fix the bold appearance in Firefox.

Comment: `font-weight` (unsurprisingly) affects font weight, not font smoothing. Adding it to @font-face declarations will cause confusion if the linked font file is not a normal-weight font file.

Comment: @MikeMeyer Actually I agree with Aaron's comment. Adding font-weight: normal to a font include that is a "light" font would *seem* to add confusion, but it should only confuse the novice developer. It's actually good practice to specify a default of normal in my experience. Normal in this case refers to "normal" for the included font and the characters being used, and is not intended to specify information about the font face itself. In many cases it'll (particularly on large platforms) reduce the likelihood of bugs coming from the all-too-typical bad architecture you see around font styles.

Comment: In fact, the name of the font face itself should denote the weight of the font by default...!

Comment: @dudewad that’s great that you agree, and yeah, it’s a decent (though rather tersely-worded) “pro-tip” about `font-weight`. Thing is, OP wasn’t asking about `font-weight`—he was asking about _antialiasing_. This is a correct answer for a completely different question.

Comment: @MikeMeyer you're totally right. I get a little carried away sometimes. ;)