# How to use Anti-aliasing in fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts

Is there any way to use anti aliasing in big fonts?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Chead/HX5nv/

im using this code in exemple:

```
<span style="font-size: 70px; font-family: arial; font-weight: bold;">
     Im a CLEAN text bold!
</span>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459746/css3-webfont-smoothing-and-antialiasing-in-firefox-and-opera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks antialiased to me in IE10. Font rendering has always been inconsistent between browsers.

If you're using Chrome (or another Webkit browser), try adding this:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```