# Font smoothing does not work for in all my browsers

Tags: css, fonts

I am using Safari, Chrome, Internet Explorer 9, and Firefox, but I have tried every font smoothing [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) rule, but the font is still being rendered as crispy.

Here's what I have tried

```
-webkit-font-smoothing
-moz-osx-font-smoothing
```

And I am trying to avoid the use of shadows and strokes.

Comment: Why not use a text shadow? Something like: `text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);`

Comment: Apparently this rule works just for browsers running on iOS. I got no idea.

Comment: That does not work for me. and I am also trying not to use  that

Comment: what is `-moz-osx-`? The vendor prefix is simply `-moz-` for Mozilla's rendering engine.

Comment: The -moz-osx- is what should work for font smoothing in mozilla this is in reference to an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459746/css3-webfont-smoothing-and-antialiasing-in-firefox-and-opera grayscale antialiasing.