# CSS of Photoshop text effects

Tags: html, css, text, photoshop

There are some text effects in Photoshop like **Crisp, sharp, strong, smooth**
How can I generate the css for these effects

Comment: Those effect are not possible in css.

Comment: Is there any alternate??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS can't succeed the styles of Photoshop but I know the following tool that applies every possible CSS style and effect to the images of any website. It only uses CSS and jQuery and with the help of the supplied editor you don't need to know CSS. I haven't seen similar tool.
http://image-styles-and-effects.impression-estudio.gr/

Answer (score 1):

The above effects are not possible in CSS. However, there are others. There is a style in CSS3 `font-smooth:always;` You can use it to have smooth fonts. You can also use `font-weight`, `font-variant` and `font-size` . A combination of all the above styles can give you a result near to the photoshop effects.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what effect you're trying to achieve. CSS will not be capable of *all* the text effects of Photoshop but will be able to reproduce an approximation of some of them.

Do you have images of the effects you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Ah, apologies if I've misunderstood; you mentioned shadow styles in your question. I would add to the above answer (I don't have enough rep to comment on it direct) that `font-smooth:always` has, apparently, been removed from the CSS3 spec. See this link on MDN: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font-smooth)

Answer (score 0):

The options you mentioned are not "effects" but modes how photoshop renders text - or how much anti-aliasing is used. If you want to use PS for a website Design, type some text in the browser (if possible in the used font) - make a screenshot and adjust PS so that it fits best.

This is not a real answer - as these are not effects you can rebuild via css, but try this:

[Forcing anti-aliasing using css: Is this a myth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761778/forcing-anti-aliasing-using-css-is-this-a-myth)