# CSS: why letters in chrome are surrounded with different color in pixel zoom?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap jumbotron which has an h1 header. When I changed that h1 header to h2 I figure out that the letters surrounded color was change:

image with h1 header:

[image]

image with h2 header:

[image]

image1 html code :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
     <h1>Admin Template</h1>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

image1 css code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
.jumbotron h1, .jumbotron .h1 {
    font-size: 63px;
}
.jumbotron h1, .jumbotron .h1 {
    color: inherit;
}
h1, .h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
}
h1, .h1, h2, .h2, h3, .h3 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6 {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.1;
    color: #fff;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.67em 0;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
h1 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
Inherited from div.jumbotron
.jumbotron {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: #252830;
}
Inherited from body
body {
    font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #CFD2DA;
    background-color: #252830;
    font-weight: 300;
}
Inherited from html
html {
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
Pseudo ::before element
*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

image2 html code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
     <h2>Admin Template</h2>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

image2 css code:

```
h2, .h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
}
h1, .h1, h2, .h2, h3, .h3 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6 {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.1;
    color: #fff;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
h2 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.83em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.83em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
Inherited from div.jumbotron
.jumbotron {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: #252830;
}
Inherited from body
body {
    font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #CFD2DA;
    background-color: #252830;
    font-weight: 300;
}
Inherited from html
html {
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
Pseudo ::before element
*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Is there any explanations to this behavior ?
Is it possible to always surround text with gray color ?

Comment: something related to text Anti alias. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761778/forcing-anti-aliasing-using-css-is-this-a-myth

Comment: That's just anti-aliasing.

Comment: but why i got different behavior ? sometimes surrounded by different colors and sometimes by gray only

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your text properties.

```
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Thanks.